# How do I set an environment variable at boot time (via a script)?

Tags: server, startup, environment-variables

I'd like to set a couple of environment variables (at boot time) on an Ubuntu machine (10.04), but I want to create their value via a script, much like:

```
export THE_ENV_VAR=$(script_to_execute_and_use_stdout_from)
```

- The reason I want to do this is that the commands used to set the environment variables take long time to execute (10s or so), so that's why I only want to do it once after boot. Anyway, currently I solved this by caching the result of the command at boot time, so that subsequent calls will go fast, thus not using env. variables at all.

I've tried setting in `/etc/environment`, but that only copies rhs verbatim

I've tried executing a script in `/etc/init.d/` at startup, but that does not seem to work.

Ideas?

Answer (score 11):

To set system-wide environmental variables that are available on boot you place them in `/etc/environment`.
This file is not a script file, but rather consists of assignment expressions, one per line. Like this:

```
SYSTEM_FOO=barnone
```

**Note**: Variable expansion does not work in /etc/environment.

Original information from [help.ubuntu.com](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables)

Comment: it won't work if the value of the enviroment key is "#" and there is no way to scape it; I test it on debian

Comment: Thank you so much. In my case I just have a normal string. it works

Comment: FYI this only apply for pam-sessions not e.g. systemd daemons (units/timers), it all depends of one mean by "system-wide"

Answer (score 5):

Put that in `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc`

```
gedit ~/.bashrc
```

Use .bash_profile if you need to use those variable with non-interactive shells (scripts) and ~/.bashrc if you are setting your variables in a shell.

If that does not work, we need more details, in particular what variables are you setting and for what purpose ?

Comment: This is not at boot time...

Answer (score 1):

While this isn't likely a good practice, you can specify environment variables as kernel parameters. The Linux kernel [documentation](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/bootparam.7.html) has some good information around it (important paragraph bolded):

> #### The argument list
>
> The kernel command line is parsed into a list of
> strings (boot  arguments) separated by spaces.  Most of the boot
> arguments have the  form:
>
> ```
>  name[=value_1][,value_2]...[,value_10]
> ```
>
> where 'name' is a unique keyword that is used to identify what part
> of the kernel the associated values (if any) are to be given to.  Note
> the limit of 10 is real, as the present code handles only 10  comma
> separated parameters per keyword.  (However, you can reuse the  same
> keyword with up to an additional 10 parameters in unusually complicated situations, > assuming the setup function supports it.)
>
> Most of the sorting is coded in the kernel source file init/main.c.
> First, the kernel checks to see if the argument is any of the special
> arguments 'root=', 'nfsroot=', 'nfsaddrs=', 'ro', 'rw', 'debug' or
> 'init'.  The meaning of these special arguments is described below.
>
> Then it walks a list of setup functions to see if the specified argument string
> (such as 'foo') has been associated with a setup function
> ('foo_setup()') for a particular device or part of the kernel.  If
> you passed the kernel the line foo=3,4,5,6 then the kernel would
> search the bootsetups array to see if 'foo' was registered.  If it
> was, then it would call the setup function associated with 'foo'
> (foo_setup()) and hand it the arguments 3, 4, 5, and 6 as given on
> the kernel command line.
>
> **Anything of the form 'foo=bar' that is not accepted as a setup function as
> described above is then interpreted as an environment variable to be set.
>
> A (useless?) example would be to use 'TERM=vt100' as
> a boot argument.**
>
> Any remaining arguments that were not picked up by the kernel and
> were not interpreted as environment variables are then passed onto
> PID 1, which is usually the init(1) program.  The most common argument
> that is passed to the init process is the word 'single' which
> instructs it to boot the computer in single user mode, and not launch
> all the usual daemons.  Check the manual page for the version of
> init(1) installed on your system to see what arguments it accepts.

[This](https://askubuntu.com/a/19487/533049) AskUbuntu answer has some good instructions on how to modify your kernel boot parameters.

Answer (score -1):

Put your commands into `/etc/rc.local`. Make sure to read the comments at the head.

Comment: Ok, tried that too, but it doesn't seem to work either, when I login after rebooting the variables don't exist :(