# Identify which grub menu item used when booting

Tags: boot, grub2

Is it possible to test which menu item was used to start the system. If the choice of kernel was different i can for example do this in my login script

```bsh
if uname -r | grep -q lowlatency; then
    jack-start
fi
```

But relying on kernel release seams ugly. I like to use the boot menu for such things is that I use the boot menu for choosing kernel/operating system anyway so doing more after startup takes more time.

Possible solutions i thought of other than using `uname` are

- Set an environment variable when invoking the boot-menu entry. If this is possible is quite nice
- I have configured grub to remember last used entry. Can I get what entry it was from somewhere? Yes, I found the file `/boot/grub/grubenv`

Comment: Can you post that as an answer instead, if you have solved your problem?

Comment: @muru It is a hack that works. But setting an environment variable would be a nicer solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution I found:

- The file `/boot/grub/grubenv` contains the name of the chosen entry

So I can now use

```bsh
if grep -q 'Whatever' /boot/grub/grubenv; then
#   do stuff    
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way, using `proc/cmdline`, example:

```
BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-37-generic root=UUID=4c0c4c6d-708b-45b0-b9e9-a5e6a7de491e ro persistent quiet splash
```

It's possible to use `~/.bashrc`, to set a custom environment variable that it's value depends on `proc/cmdline`. As you can add a custom Linux boot parameter if you think `/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-37-generic` is not enough to identify it.

Reference:

- [Set environment variable from GRUB](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/set-environment-variable-from-grub-471990/)
- [How can grub pass any custom variable into system enviroment?](https://superuser.com/questions/385734/how-can-grub-pass-any-custom-variable-into-system-enviroment)
- [How do I set an environment variable at boot time (via a script)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65563/how-do-i-set-an-environment-variable-at-boot-time-via-a-script)

Comment: But then I have to check whether my identification string is not used by the kernel so reading the grub environment file seems more safe

Comment: @user877329, Agree, but it's not a big deal, use hard naming, ex: `kernel_type_XYZ=Whatever`